# Is it possible to access the screenshot mechanism as a trigger action?

Tags: ios, photos

I'd like to modify the outcome of what happens when you take a screenshot. Is that possible to any degree?

Comment: You are referring screenshot as taking screenshot in your application or the default iPhone functionality?

Answer (score 1):

You can be notified that a user took a screenshot by registering for the `UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification` notification.

But that's it. The notification does not contain any useful information.

The best you could do is to use the Photos framework and locate the latest picture in the Screenshots album (finding pictures with a collection subtype of `PHAssetCollectionSubtypeSmartAlbumScreenshots`).

Once you have access to desired `PHAsset`, you can make whatever changes you need using `PHAssetChangeRequest`.